# Comparing files in folders in windows

Tags: backup, nas, storage, onedrive, home-directory

I am in need of a solution that allows me to compare a sum of of files within two different directories. I was performing a half terabyte copy to Onedrive for business from a NAS device when some files wouldn't copy over because their file names was too long... so is there any way to determine the files that weren't copied over between these two?

Using Windows 10 Home, sync was paused during the copy for one drive... if that helps

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is Microsoft SyncToy: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155. It's GUI based and allows you to define folder pairs to synchronize. There is a preview button which gives you a list of files that are yet required to be synchronized. (This is the list you want.) After syncronization it outputs any problems encountered in a list.

It's old, so the system requirements listed on Microsofts website are a bit outdated. I successfully use it regularly on Windows 8.1. I've not used it on Windows 10, but it should work there, too.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental sync tool is the ubiquitous unix rsync, and you want it on windows. It can find the missing files and copy them over. It can do a lot more than that but it seems this will satisfy your needs.

**cwRsync** is basically rsync for windows that even comes with a client GUI for ease of use: https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync

> Rsync uses the Rsync algorithm which provides a very fast method for bringing remote files into sync. It does this by sending just the differences in the files across the link, without requiring that both sets of files are present at one of the ends of the link beforehand. At first glance this may seem impossible because the calculation of diffs between two files normally requires local access to both files.

---

**DeltaCopy** is an alternative, you may find the GUI less intimidating perhaps, open source as well:
http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

> In general terms, DeltaCopy is an open source, fast incremental backup
>   program. Let's say you have to backup one file that is 500 MB every
>   night. A normal file copy would copy the entire file even if a few
>   bytes have changed. DeltaCopy, on the other hand, would only copy the
>   part of file that has actually been modified. This reduces the data
>   transfer to just a small fraction of 500 MB saving time and network
>   bandwidth.
>
> In technical terms, DeltaCopy is a "Windows Friendly" wrapper around
>   the Rsync program, currently maintained by Wayne Davison. "rsync" is
>   primarily designed for Unix/Linux/BSD systems. Although ports are
>   available for Windows, they typically require downloading Cygwin
>   libraries and manual configuration.